# How can I create e new "recent search" button using the code I have created? I am still getting error messages in dev tools and not sure what to do

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working to create not only a space for recent searches in local storage but also to create a new working button on my main project page once functioning. I am receiving an error message that the "addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler); call I have at the very bottom of my code cannot read property of "null" so I'm wondering where I went wrong in the starting piece. I have tried to rework this piece of JS so many times now and I'm just not sure where to go from here at this point. Any advice?

```js
var cityFormEl = document.querySelector("#city");
var cityNameInputEl = document.querySelector("#location");
var dateFormEl = document.querySelector("#date");
var dateNameInputEl = document.querySelector("#today");
var historyButtonsEl = document.querySelector("#search-item");
var historyCardEl = document.querySelector("#recent-searches");
var trashEl = document.querySelector("#trash");
var searchHistoryArray = []

var formSubmitHandler = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get city name value from input element

    var cityBtn = cityNameInputEl.value.trim();

    // Set city name in local storage and generate history buttons

    if (cityBtn) {
        searchHistoryArray.push(cityBtn);
        localStorage.setItem("citySearch", JSON.stringify(searchHistoryArray));
        localStorage.setItem("dateSearch", JSON.stringify(searchHistoryArray));
        var searchHistoryEl = document.createElement('button');
        searchHistoryEl.className = "btn";
        searchHistoryEl.setAttribute("data-city", "data-date", cityBtn)
        searchHistoryEl.innerHTML = cityBtn;
        historyButtonsEl.appendChild(searchHistoryEl);
        historyCardEl.removeAttribute("style")
        cityNameInputEl.value = "";
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter a Date and a City name");
    }
}


// Load any past city searches

var loadHistory = function () {
    searchArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("citySearch"));
    if (searchArray) {
        searchHistoryArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("citySearch", "dateSearch"));
        for (let i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
            var searchHistoryEl = document.createElement('button');
            searchHistoryEl.className = "btn";
            searchHistoryEl.setAttribute("data-city", "data-date", searchArray[i])
            searchHistoryEl.innerHTML = searchArray[i];
            historyButtonsEl.appendChild(searchHistoryEl);
            historyCardEl.removeAttribute("style");
        }
    }
}

// Search using search history buttons

var buttonClickHandler = function (event) {
    var cityBtn = event.target.getAttribute("data-city", "data-date",);
    if (cityBtn) {
        formSubmitHandler(cityBtn);
    }
}

// Clear Search History

var clearHistory = function (event) {
    localStorage.removeItem("citySearch", "dateSearch");
    historyCardEl.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
}
cityFormEl.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);
historyButtonsEl.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler);
trashEl.addEventListener("click", clearHistory);
loadHistory();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Adventure Time</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adventure-time/assets/css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adventure-time/build/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <a href="#"><img class="max-w-xs p-8" src="../adventure-time/assets/img/adventure-time-logo-reverse.png"
                    alt="Logo of Adventure Time" /></a>
            <a href="#recent-searches" class="recent-search-nav">Recent Searches</a>

        </nav>
        <section class="hero">
            <div class="hero-statement">
                <h2>
                    Your <span id="adventure"> Adventure</span> <br />
                    Starts here
                </h2>
                <p>Enter a time and place to start your journey</p>
                <br />

            </div>
            <form class="search-input flex justify-between">
                <div id="date">
                    <input type="date" id="today" name="date" value="2021-08-01" min="2021-08-01" max="2022-12-31"
                        class="date-input cst-btn cst-btn-lft">
                </div>
                <div class="time-input cst-btn cst-btn-cntr"><input type="time" id="time" name="time" min="07:00"
                        max="22:00" required></div>
                <div class="location-input cst-btn cst-btn-cntr">
                    <div id="city">
                        <label>City</label>
                        <input id="location" type="text" tabindex="3" name="city">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="cst-btn cst-btn-rgt" id="search"><a href=adventure.html>Find my Adventure</a></button>
            </form>
        </section>
        <!-- HERO END -->
    </header>
    <main class="m-auto w-3/4">
        <div id="recent-searches">
            <h2 class="text-black text-4xl text-center">Recent Searches</h2>
            <div class="recent-searches flex justify-around">
                <div class="search-item">
                    <h4>Los Angeles, CA</h4>
                    <p>Sat, Jul 7 at 3:00 PM</p>
                </div>
                <div class="search-item">
                    <h4>Portland, OR</h4>
                    <p>Sat, Jul 7 at 3:00 PM</p>
                </div>
                <div class="search-item">
                    <h4>New York, NY</h4>
                    <p>Sat, Jul 7 at 3:00 PM</p>
                </div>
                <div class="search-item">
                    <h4>Vancouver, BC</h4>
                    <p>Sat, Jul 7 at 3:00 PM</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <h5>Made with ❤️&nbsp by Team Awesome</h5>
    </footer>
    <script src="../adventure-time/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got this error (although I am not entirely sure if this is what you are referencing):

```
Uncaught TypeError: historyButtonsEl is null
```

The reason this TypeError is being thrown lies in this line of your JS:

```js
var historyButtonsEl = document.querySelector("#search-item");
```

You are selecting for an element that has an **ID** equal to 'search-item'; however, the only reference to 'search-item' in your html is a **class**. To fix this, simply do:

```js
var historyButtonsEl = document.querySelector(".search-item");
```

Notice the '.' instead of a '#'. '#' select **id**s whereas '.' select **classes**. Also, although I am unsure what you are trying to select with this querySelector(), I ought to warn you that selecting classes with querySelector() will return the first found element with that class and **not** all elements with that class (to do that use querySelectorAll()). Hopefully this helped.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have been trying to figure out where the issue was and something so small like that has been tripping me up for the longest time! The '#' vs '.' for identifiers seems to be tripping me up more than I thought it would! I really appreciate it! Looks like I have another spot to update, I'm getting it again on the trashEl even listener as well.